# Mongoose query taking 300ms for find query in collection which contains 0 documents

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Every query, that I run in my application it is taking an extra overload of 250-300ms don't know why! I have my mongodb and server both hosted on AWS. There are security groups monitoring the connection. Our both hosted ones are t2.medium. The query when I am running on Mongodb Compass, is taking 0ms, but the same query through application, 300ms.
Please help resolve it.

My mongoose query ->

```
const res = await payeeCollection.find({}); // returns empty array as the collection does not contain any documents.
```

mongodb-util.js

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import config from 'config';

const {
  mongo_db: {
    uri,
    database
  }
} = config;

if (!(uri && database)) {
  throw new Error('FATAL: Config File Missing');
}

const mongoDbConnection = mongoose.createConnection(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});

mongoDbConnection.on("connecting", () => {
  console.log("attempting to create a connection with mongodb")
});

mongoDbConnection.on("open", () => {
  console.log('connection with mongodb successfully created')
});

mongoDbConnection.on("error", (err) => {
  console.log('error in creating a connection with mongo db, error: ', err);
});

export default mongoDbConnection;
```

collectionSchema.js

```js
import {
  paymentLinkSchema
} from "../schemas/paymentLink.schema.js";
import mongoDbConnection from "../utils/mongo-db.util.js";
import config from "config";

const {
  mongo_db: {
    database
  },
} = config;

const checkWriterDb = mongoDbConnection.useDb(database);

const PaymentLinkCollection = checkWriterDb.model(
  "paymentLink",
  paymentLinkSchema
);
```

```
[Postman Api hit time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCkxi.png)
[Simple one query code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmgMz.png)
[Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGttq.png)
```

Comment: Can you share your `mongoose` query in the issue description?

Comment: Yeah I added it, can you see now? @RobinThomas

Comment: Yes. Can you share your mongoose config and how its getting connected to mongodb?